# RAILS... can not use controller variables on views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, dictionary, collections, controller

i wanna use this controller variables on my views like always
but

```
def new
 @lease_type = LeaseType.new
 @vehicle_types = VehicleType.all
 user_id = current_user.id
 @parking = Parking.where(owner: user_id).last
 @lease_times = LeaseTime.all
end
```

but on my views if i use it
[image]

[image]

so i read... and say i must have the things like this. but i thinks is better use what i send from controller instead of Model access from view.

[image]

then i wanna use de @parking.id here
[image]

but

[image]

SO!??? why can not access use it?  Thanks for help

**Update:**

the create method

[image]

the parameters [image]
and

```
[![enter code here][8]][8]
```

Comment: Can you show your create method on LeaseTypesController?

Comment: that is create, not new...

Comment: ??!  we have 2 methods this 1 the new is where you have the form and create is when you save... u.u 
i know that i can get some of this attributes on controller like parking id when save but need the other collections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes because you have loaded that data in the `new` action but not in `create` action. And when you try to create a new `LeaseType` and if there are any errors it renders the `new` action again and now the variables doesn't have the value you fetched in `new` action. So you can write a `before_action` which will run on both `new` and `create` and load the data for you like this:

Add a `before_action` on the controller:

```
def load_data
  @vehicle_types = VehicleType.all
  @parking = Parking.where(owner: current_user.id).last
  @lease_times = LeaseTime.all
end
```

Change the `new` action to:

```
def new
  @lease_type = LeaseType.new
end
```

And on the top in controller add:

```
before_action :load_data, only: [:new, :create]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep i solved... But your answer is a better way thanks a LOT! 

i dont know how to delete or close the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

seems good but no work properly "nil"... when use your load_date method

so i put the @collections on new and create directly and works.

something like this